# Cloud code : deploy to cloud run didn't work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-code, google-cloud-shell-editor

I'm trying to deploy my app using Google Cloud Run but it didn't work, there's no error appear, so I'm pretty confused, I've been waiting for an hour but nothing happened (just a blank page) like this screenshot:
[UI deployment didn't show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaKNb.png)
which should bring up like, service setting option, service name, container image URL, like this picture:
[UI deployment should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCURA.png)

any help will mean a lot to me, Thank you

Comment: Check the Cloud Run logs

Comment: thanks for the answer @John Hanley, I've checked the logs but still no error or warning appears.

Comment: This seems like you may be encountering a bug, I would recommend opening a bug report: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hikmah for filing a Github issue [#462](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode/issues/462) and getting to bottom of it, the SDK managed by VSCode got in to bad state, so had to be deleted and re-installed. we have fix coming for this in the next release. Sorry for inconvenience!